# select an option by using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I have this html code:

```
<select data-val="true" data-val-number="Int32。" data-val-required="Int32" id="CategoryData" name="ParentId" onchange="sel3(this);">
<option value="0">-- category --</option>
<option selected="selected" value="845">a</option>
<option value="846">b</option>
<option value="847">c</option>
</select>
```

I want to extract the text "a", "b", "c".

My code:

```
select_box = driver.find_element_by_id("CategoryList3") 
options = [x for x in select_box.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")] 
for element in options:
    print (element.get_attribute("text"))
```

Output:

```
-- category --
a
b
c
```

this will also output "-- category --", but I don't want this one.
I am pretty new to selenium, so any advice is appreciated!

Comment: `-- category --` is one of the element within `<option>` tag, so I think you have to manipulate the `List` yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just checking that value is not 0?

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
select_box = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("CategoryList3"))
for option in select_box.options:
    if option.get_attribute('value') != '0':
        print(option.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can remove 1st element in list using slicing.

just modify 'options to options[1:]'  in for loop

```
select_box = driver.find_element_by_id("CategoryList3") 
options = [x for x in select_box.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")] 
for element in options[1:]:
    print (element.get_attribute("text"))
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract the text "a", "b", "c" from the given `HTML` you can use the following code block :

```
option_select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('CategoryData'))
for opt in option_select.options:
    if ("-- category --" not in opt.get_attribute('innerHTML')):
        print(opt.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

> I have used `innerHTML` instead of using `value` as your question was to exclude the option with text `-- category --` but not any `value`.